# Pigeon Hole Principle : Can one of the games be played?

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Q:  9 people are in a club. Each of them can play one of the games among Bridge , Hearts & Mahajong. Prove that they can play at least one of the mentioned games.( all games require 4 players.)

I came across this question over the internet. It seems that if we use Pigeonhole principle then we can prove that we can easily distribute 3 players in each of the three games and thus say that they cannot play any of the game.

I am new to Pigeon Hole principle and so not very sure about my answer. Any rectification will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. Maybe rewrite the problem so that there are 10 people in a club.

Comment: Absolutely... Thanks a lot.